Micropython Web Server unexpectedly stops working after a while
I'm working on a WoL script for my Raspberry Pi Pico W. The goal is to be able to wake up my pc from anywhere using a request to the right IP and webpage.
Currently, I'm having an issue with the pico unexpectedly stopping to respond to any tcp request after a while.
Here is what I've tried to fix the issue:

Make sure the network power management plan is set to WLAN.PM_NONE
Make sure the time is set properly using ntptime
Tried to call machine.reset() every 2 hours

Here is a MRE:
import ntptime,network,time
from machine import Pin
import uasyncio as asyncio

SSID = '' # Put your WifI SSID
PASS = '' # Put your WiFi password

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head> <title>Hello</title></head>
 <body>
     <button onclick="turnOn()">Turn On</button>
     <script>
        function turnOn(){
             fetch("/wakeup");
        }
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
 """

ROOT="/"
WOL_ROUTE="/wakeup"
onboard = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT, value=0)

def connect_to_network():

    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

    wlan.config(pm=network.WLAN.PM_NONE)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(SSID, PASS)

    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        time.sleep(1)
        
    print(f"Local IP: {wlan.ifconfig()[0]}")

    ntptime.settime()
    print("Time synced")


async def serve_client(reader, writer):
    addr,port = reader.get_extra_info("peername")
    print('Got a connection from %s:%s' % (addr,port))
        
    request_line = await reader.readline()
    # We are not interested in HTTP request headers, skip them
    while await reader.readline() != b"\r\n":
        pass

    request = request_line.decode("utf-8")

    method,route,protocol = request.strip().split(" ")
    print("Method: %s" % method)
    print("Route: %s" % route)
    print("Protocol: %s" % protocol)
    
    if route == WOL_ROUTE:
        print("Sending magic packet")
        # [...] WoL is working no need to include it here
        writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: application/json\r\n\r\n')
        writer.write('{"status":"switched on"}')
    elif route == ROOT:
        print("Sending WebPage")
        writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        writer.write(html)
        
    await writer.drain()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print("Client disconnected")

async def main():
    connect_to_network()
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.start_server(serve_client, "0.0.0.0", 80))
    while True:
        onboard.on()
        await asyncio.sleep(.25)
        onboard.off()
        await asyncio.sleep(4.75)
        
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    asyncio.new_event_loop()

